# Cannot disable reminders for calendar events

Tags: android, calendar, google-calendar-api, reminders

I want a calendar event WITHOUT reminders. I have the following code:

```
private void addToCalendar(Context ctx, String missedCallName,
        String phoneNumber, int missedCallImportance, long startTime,
        long endTime, SharedPreferences sp) {
    ContentResolver cr = ctx.getContentResolver();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    long realStartTime = 0;

    if (missedCallImportance == MOST_IMPORTANT_CONTACT) {
        realStartTime = startTime
                + mins(NEEDED_MINS_BEFORE_AND_AFTER_CALLS);
        values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART, realStartTime);
        values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DURATION, "+P"
                + NEEDED_MINS_FOR_IMPORTANT_CALLS + "M");

    }
    // ki kell hagyni egy helyet a fontos kontaktnak
    else {
        realStartTime = startTime + mins(NEEDED_MINS_FOR_IMPORTANT_CALLS);
        values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART, realStartTime);
        values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DURATION, "+P"
                + NEEDED_MINS_FOR_OTHER_CALLS + "M");

    }

    values.put(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, "Call " + missedCallName);
    values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DESCRIPTION, "Phone number: "
            + phoneNumber);

    TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getDefault();
    values.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, timeZone.getID());

    // values.put(CalendarContract.Events.HAS_ALARM, false);
    values.put(CalendarContract.Events.HAS_ALARM, 0);

    // default calendar
    values.put(CalendarContract.Events.CALENDAR_ID, 1);

    // insert event to calendar
    Uri uri = cr.insert(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI, values);

}
```

The problem:
Sometimes (maybe every 2nd time) there are reminders for the event in the calendar... (alert and email reminders)

What am I doing wrong? I don't want any reminders!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was because of the default Google Calendar settings...